# Java Hibernate @Table name as a parameter

Tags: java, database, hibernate, parameters

I have a table definition in class called `Message`, with hibernate annotation `@Table(name="message")`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="message")
public class Message implements Serializable
```

So I am able to create `Message` objects and store them into database table `message` from java code.

What I would like to do is to tell `Message` object what table name should be used, e.g. I would like to create it with parameter like `Message(String tableName)`. Then the table name annotation would be used from that parameter, like

```
@Entity
@Table(name=tableName)
public class Message implements Serializable
```

Everything other should be the same.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the table names using NamingStrategies.

```
public class MyNamingStrategy extends DefaultNamingStrategy {

   @Override
   public  String tableName(String tableName) {
   return tableName;
 }
}
```

Then use as follows.

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory;
Configuration config = new AnnotationConfiguration()
.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
.setNamingStrategy( new MyNamingStrategy () );
sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```